# Cannot set property 'clientMutationId' of undefined

Tags: relayjs

I am getting following error. when trying to run a mutation via graphiql. Please help me resolve this issue or point to a link where I can find react relay mutations example.

```js
mutation {
  createUser(input: {username: "Hamza Khan", clientMutationId: ""}) {
    user {
      id
      username
    }
  }
}

{
  "data": {
    "createUser": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot set property 'clientMutationId' of undefined",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 17,
          "column": 2
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Here is the mutation definition

```js
import {
  GraphQLString,
  GraphQLInt,
  GraphQLFloat,
  GraphQLList,
  GraphQLObjectType,
  GraphQLID,
  GraphQLNonNull
} from 'graphql';

import {
  connectionArgs,
  connectionDefinitions,
  connectionFromArray,
  fromGlobalId,
  globalIdField,
  mutationWithClientMutationId,
  nodeDefinitions,
} from 'graphql-relay';

import {User} from './usermodel';
import {UserType} from './usertype';

export const UserMutations = {};
UserMutations.createUser = mutationWithClientMutationId({
  name: 'CreateUser',
  inputFields: {
    username: {type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)}
  },
  outputFields: {
    user: {
      type: UserType,
      resolve: (payload) => {
        return User.getUserById(payload.userId);
      }
    }
  },
  mutateAndGetPayload: (args) => {
    let newUser = new User({ username: args.username });
    newUser.save().then((user) => {
      return {userId: user.id};
    }).error((err) => {return null;});
  }
});
```

Comment: The error is almost certainly because you're not loading a user correctly. Probably because you're just sending a username as an input.

Comment: I can console log new user in mutateAndGetPayload but strangely resolve function in outputFields is not executing.

Comment: it might be you're not querying for user. If you don't request a field, the output field's resolve function isn't called.

Comment: I am querying for user with two fields Id and username.

Comment: can you add the code where you define the mutation type for your schema? e.g. where is `UserMutations.createUser` referenced?

Answer (score 13):

You have to *return* something from `mutateAndGetPayload` – in your case, a promise.

```js
mutateAndGetPayload: ({username}) => {
  const newUser = new User({username});
  return newUser.save().then(user => ({userId: user.id}));
}
```

Comment: Additionally, I'm not sure that you want to return a null payload if there's an error. You probably want to throw so that the error can bubble up through your webstack and out to Relay so that the client-side mutation can know the mutation has failed.

Comment: In my case I have a second promise within the one which is returned. And the second promise is rejected. This  causes the error "Cannot set property 'clientMutationId' of undefined" is again seen. Not sure what is the best way to handle it.

Comment: Ok my bad. A silly mistake in my code. The return was within my 'then' of the promise. I wasn't returning from the main flow.