# Cannot set property 'clientMutationId' of undefined" Error

Tags: graphql, relayjs, graphql-js

```
outputFields: {
    token: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve: (token) => token
    }
},
```

outputfields never gets called, not sure whether i am doing in a right way or not, doesn't the resolve function gets called while returning data from mutateAndGetPayload method.

```
mutateAndGetPayload: (credentials) => {
    console.log('credentials', credentials);
    userprof.findOne({email: credentials.email}).exec(function(err, r) {
        if(!r) {
            return new Error('no user')
        } else if(r) {
            if(r.password != credentials.password) {
                return new Error('password error');
            } else {
                var token = jwt.getToken(r);
                console.log(token);
                return {token};
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33831911/cannot-set-property-clientmutationid-of-undefined

Comment: "outputfields never gets called" -- how do you know that?

Comment: @AhmadFerdous if it would have been called then it shoulds print the token in graphiql

Comment: What do you see when you put a `console.log(token);` debug statement in `resolve: (token) => token` of output fields? Do you see an object with `token` property? Because you're returning an object in `mutateAndGetPayload` function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you need to return something from the mutateAndGetPayload method. That could be a promise. Try to return the userprof.findOne.

Answer (score 2):

Solution

```
    token: {
        type: GraphQLString,
        resolve: ({token}) => token
    }
},
mutateAndGetPayload: (credentials) => {
    return UserProf.findOne({ email: credentials.email }).then((r) => {
        if (!r) {
            return new Error('no user');
        } else if (r) {
            if (r.password != credentials.password) {
                return new Error('password error');
            } else {
                return { token: jwt.getToken(r) };
            }
        }
    });
}
```